# Сравнение многомерных массивов

Tags: массивы, php, сравнение

Здравствуйте.

Имеется некая структура вида:

```
$head_array = array($params1 => $params2);
$array1[array($params1)][array($params2)] = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2[array($params1)][array($params2)] = array(3,4,6,4,5);
```

Необходимо сравнить третий вложенный массив (цифры), как сделать это правильней? Ключи массивов у `$array1` и `$array2` одинаковые, и сравнивать нужно массивы по одинаковым ключам, соответственно (надеюсь, объяснил понятно).
Грубо говоря, вывод цифр, которых нет в первом массиве, но есть во втором (и наоборот).

```
foreach($array1 as $param1 => $params2){
        foreach($params2 as $param2 => $nums){
                foreach($nums as $num){
                        if(!in_array($num,$array2[$param1][$param2])){
                                echo "error. $num at $param1 ($param2) in array1, but not in array2\n";
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Так, естественно, работать не будет.

```
foreach($head_array as $param1 => $param2){  
    $diff = array_diff($array1[$param1][$param2],$array2[$param1][$param2]);  
}
```

Так тоже.

Comment: @berestnev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
$diff = array_intersect(arr1, arr2)
```

Все описано в [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Вычисляет расхождение массивов, переданных как аргументы. Но вообще, Вам бы разобраться в Вашей структуре. Попробуйте упростить.

Answer (score 1):

Я написал собственную рекурсивную функцию, с помощью которой можно найти все отличающийся элементы. Это хорошо работает для моей задачи, однако вам возможно придётся отредактировать её. Обратите внимания, что список изменений будет передаваться по ссылке в первый переданный массив изменяя его.

```
<?php

function my_array_diff (&$arr1, &$arr2) {
    $all_same = true;
    $diff = [];
    if(is_array($arr1) and is_array($arr2)) {
        foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
            $all_same = my_array_diff($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]);
            if (!$all_same) {
                $diff[] = $key;
            } else {
                unset($arr1[$key]);
            }
        }
        if (count($diff) > 0) $all_same = false;
    } else {
        if ((string) $arr1 === (string) $arr2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $arr1 = $arr1.' / '.$arr2;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $all_same;
}
$array1 = array("a" => array(1, 2, 4), "b" => array('q' => array(1,3),
                'w' => array('e' => array(1,2))), "c" => "blue", 'i' => 'q');
$array2 = array("a" => array(1, 2, 3), "b" => array('q' => array(1,2),
                'w' => array('e' => array(1,2))), "c" => "blue");
my_array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($array1);
```

Результат:

> Array ( [a] => Array ( [2] => 4 / 3 ) [b] => Array ( [q] => Array ( [1] => 3 / 2 ) ) [i] => q / )